# SpringBoot Unable to add the BCFIPS provider while running the executable war

Tags: spring-boot, bouncycastle, fips

I'm trying to use the BCFIPS Provider in SpringBoot application. After running the SprintBoot executable war file it is throwing the following error. I couldn't find any info on this error if anyone has a any idea on this please help me.

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {



public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (Security.getProvider("BCFIPS") == null) {
            Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider(), 1);
        }
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: entry
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.checksumValidate(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.isReady(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.getDefaultMode(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to diagnose the problem. For example what versions of Spring Boot and BouncyCastle are you using. A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve) would make it a lot easier for people to try to help you

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to download the bc-fips.jar again and check the checksum.

Also, it doesn't work when you do that in the main method. (This is using Spring-Boot 1.5.11-RELEASE)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public Cipher cbcCipher() throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider());
    return Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BCFIPS");
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using maven to manage the dependencies and it downloaded fresh bc-fips jar. I also created a Bean but the checksum error still shows up.